# Html. Нарисовать линию

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно нарисовать или любым иным способом провести линию от одного блока div к другому. Т.е. два элемента связать линией. Элементы генерируются динамически.

Строится все это дело на основе уровней. Например, есть пользователь с уровнем 1. Он будет на самом верху. Дальше пользователи с уровнем 2, они ниже. Нужно их соединить любым способом, как на схеме.
Схематичный пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите вашу разметку с div'ами.

Comment: @AK, ничего особенного, два блока div. Пример добавил в вопрос

Comment: Есть подозрение что тут `svg` или канва нужна.

Comment: @Aid, можно ли это реализовать с помощью canvas? Если да, то не подскажите пример?

Comment: а на основе чего строится связь между блоками? это же надо учитывать...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавил в вопрос

Comment: Раз уж заговорили про svg и канву, то возможно стоит воспользоваться [d3.js](https://d3js.org/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');
var line = document.getElementById('line').getElementsByTagName('line')[0];

function shuffle() {
    var pos = {
        ft: Math.round(Math.random() * 50),
        fl: Math.round(Math.random() * 50),
        st: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 100,
        sl: Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 200
    }
    first.style.top = pos.ft + 'px';
    first.style.left = pos.fl + 'px';
    second.style.top = pos.st + 'px';
    second.style.left = pos.sl + 'px';
    line.setAttribute('x1', pos.fl + first.offsetWidth);
    line.setAttribute('y1', pos.ft + first.offsetHeight);
    line.setAttribute('x2', pos.sl);
    line.setAttribute('y2', pos.st);
}

shuffle();

document.getElementById('shuffle').addEventListener('click', shuffle);
```

```css
div {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

#line {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    stroke: #F00;
    stroke-width: 2px;
    z-index: -1;
}

#shuffle { position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 50%; }
```

```html
<div id="first"></div>
<div id="second"></div>

<svg id="line">
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" />
</svg>

<button id="shuffle">Сместить</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Вот пример с использовнием SVG:**

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
<line x1="50" y1="50" x2="80" y2="80" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
<line x1="31.5" y1="55" x2="31.5" y2="75" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
<rect x="5" y="5" width="50" height="50" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"/>
<rect x="75" y="75" width="50" height="50" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"/>
<rect x="5" y="75" width="50" height="50" fill="white" stroke="black" stroke-width="4"/>
</svg>
```